# matlab loops dependency on outer loop in averaging

Tags: matlab, loops

```
for i=1:1:rowsMax
for  j=1:1:columsMax
    array(i,j) = array(i+1,j);
    A(j) = A(j) + array(i,j);
end
end
```

How do I implement this in Matlab? I can't use parfor loops, Matlab errors with that.

Comment: Ever heard of [vectorization](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html)?

Comment: The matrix dimensions will be different

Answer (score 0):

`A` is the sum of every two adjacent rows of `array` up to `rowsMax+1`.

In other words:

```
A = sum(array(1:rowsMax,1:columnsMax) + array(2:rowsMax+1,1:columnsMax),2);
```